# Apple-app-site-association : banner displays while no file in server

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, ios10, apple-app-site-associate

I have apple-app-site-association file in my server root directory, so getting banner on my iOS safari browser, but when I remove the file from server, cleared my browser history, then reset my phone too, but still getting the banner.

**Note :** changed my app ID in the file, but not reflects in banner.

```
https://example.com/apple-app-site-association
```

apple-app-site-association file :

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "123456789.com.abc.example",
                "paths": [ "*" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Try hitting https://example.com/apple-app-site-association in your browser, if page loads that means your server cache is still returning the file, try clearing server cache or restart the server

Comment: @SandeepBhandari -  Yes, Cleared my tmp and trash folders, now getting file not found exception for `example.com/apple-app-site-association`, then cleared mobile data, but still getting banner.

Comment: I dont know how have u implemented server code, if you have some routes which points to example.com/apple-app-site-association update it properly to either return 404. But leaving that aside, your problem of banner showing up should have stopped by now

Comment: @SandeepBhandari - updated my apple file. I did not touch any server code still, just placed the file in root directory.

Answer (score 2):

Your are getting the banner still because you haven't build the app again.
During the build process of the ios app it downloads the apple-app-association-file from the asociated domain and save it in the app for deeplinking purpose.

Once you get the new build with the updated apple-app-association-file
your problem will be solved.

To remove the banner from all the pages you can just try below code:

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
        {
            "appID": "your app id here",
            "paths": [
                "NOT /*"        
            ]
        }
    ]
} }
```